# Ноль в каждой строке и каждом столбце

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Если в каждой строке и в каждом столбце можно выбрать по одному нулевому элементу, то вернуть true, иначе false.
Подкиньте хоть какие-то идеи пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, как минимум, сработает длинный путь :) - если нули заменить единицами, а ненулевые элементы - нулями, получаем задачу о паросочетаниях - вроде бы так? И если паросочетание получается, то... но это так, в порядке доказательства существования полиномиального алгоритма :)

Comment: @Harry ну да, стандартная задача о паросочетаниях.

Comment: паросочетания? тут два двойних цикла и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim Покажи)

Comment: @KoVadim присоединяюсь) как сделать в 2 двойных цикла я не знаю) знаю как в 2 функции рекурсивные.

Comment: По каждой строке делаете & между значениями строки. Если результат больше 0 - возвращаете false, если равен 0 - true. То же самое со столбцами.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Во второй матрице и там, и там - сплошные нули...

Comment: Новое условие - достаточно простой проверки на наличие нулей. Вторая матрица отвечает новому условию: в каждой строке имеется по нулевому элементу, как и в каждом столбце. Например, выберите ВСЕ нулевые элементы - и получите ваше "хотя бы по одному"...

Comment: Кстати, очень нехорошо получается - менять условие. Лучше его дописать далее, как уточнение. А так, получается, все тут дурку 3 часа валяли, решая невесть какую сложность...

Comment: ой, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Да, описал задачу я плохо, но как вы говорили, решается эта задача с помощью алгоритма "совершенное паросочетание"

Comment: Да я уже даже два варианта предложил в результате :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, еще такой вопрос по вашим примерам, как там вывести координаты выбранных нулей?

Comment: Дописал вывод, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем, если воспользоваться алгоритмом Куна поиска максимального паросочетания, и проверять его на равенство размеру матрицы, то - вот так, в лоб (честно говоря, писать красиво и эффектно просто жаль времени...) получается что-то вроде (проверку на квадратность входных матриц не делаю!!):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> p1 = { {0,4,2,2},{6,0,0,4},{0,0,6,4},{8,4,0,0}};
vector<vector<int>> p2 = { {0,6,4,4},{4,0,0,4},{0,2,8,6},{6,4,0,0}};

vector<vector<int>> bipartee(const vector<vector<int>>& q)
{
    vector<vector<int>> p;
    for(size_t r = 0; r < q.size(); ++r)
    {
        p.push_back(vector<int>());
        for(size_t c = 0; c < q.size(); ++c)
            if (q[r][c] == 0) p[r].push_back(c);
    }
    return p;
}

bool try_kuhn(int v, vector<vector<int>>& g, vector<int>& mt, vector<bool>& used)
{
    if (used[v])  return false;
    used[v] = true;
    for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) {
        int to = g[v][i];
        if (mt[to] == -1 || try_kuhn(mt[to],g,mt,used))
        {
            mt[to] = v;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool check(const vector<vector<int>>& p)
{
    int n = p.size();
    vector<vector<int>> g = bipartee(p);
    vector<int> mt;
    vector<bool> used;
    mt.assign(n, -1);
    for(int v = 0; v < n; ++v) {
        used.assign(n,false);
        try_kuhn(v,g,mt,used);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        if (mt[i] != -1) ++sum;
    if (sum == n)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            if (mt[i] != -1)
                cout << "(" << i << "," << mt[i] << ") ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return (sum == n);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "First matrix: "  << check(p1) << endl;
    cout << "Second matrix: " << check(p2) << endl;
}
```

См. http://ideone.com/Kbhydg

Раз такая сложность в восприятии... Второй вариант - ветвей и отсечений. Покороче, но в эффективности не уверен...

```
vector<vector<int>> p1 = { {0, 4, 2, 2}, {6, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 6, 4}, {8, 4, 0, 0}};
vector<vector<int>> p2 = { {0, 6, 4, 4}, {4, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 2, 8, 6}, {6, 4, 0, 0}};

bool check(const vector<vector<int>>& p, int r = 0)
{
    int n = p.size();
    static vector<bool> u;
    if (r == n) return true;

    if (r == 0) u = vector<bool>(n,false);

    for(int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
    {
        if (p[r][c] || u[c]) continue;
        u[c] = true;
        if (check(p,r+1))
        {
            cout << "(" << r << "," << c << ") ";
            if (r == 0) cout << endl;
            return true;
        }
        u[c] = false;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "First matrix: "  << check(p1) << endl;
    cout << "Second matrix: " << check(p2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Я даже не понимаю, как этот алгоритм решает исходную задачу. Судя по описанию,  оба Ваших массива должны выдавать false. а это не так.

Comment: @KoVadim http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching - вот здесь алгоритм Куна описан

Comment: @KoVadim тогда вы должны были увидеть, что код оттуда взят, с соответствующей доводкой с помощью напильника и зубила... :)

Comment: Я против решения простых задач оверинженирингом

Comment: @KoVadim Я не вижу другого варианта решения задачи. Разве что перебор и ветвление с отсечениями. Но и то, и другое мне кажется перебором :) при наличии детерминированного алгоритма. Вернее, даже, я бы сказал так - это задача, эквивалентная поиску паросочетаний, так что более простой алгоритм означает наличие более простого алгоритма поиска паросочетаний, нет?

Comment: @KoVadim Посмотрите еще один вариант у меня - ветвей и отсечений. Так сойдет или и это плохо?

Comment: Пусть автор точно задачу сформулирует. А то оно у него меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Написал решение в лоб. Ему не хватает ещё пары проверок, но думаю сойдет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef  vector<vector<int>> matrix;

bool check(const matrix m) {
    // проверим матрицу
    if (m.size() == 0 || m[0].size() == 0) return false;
    // первый проход
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].size(); j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == 0) count++;
        }
        if (count != 1) return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m[0].size(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size(); j++) {
            if (m[j][i] == 0) count++;
        }
        if (count != 1) return false;
    }

    return true;    
}

int main() {
    matrix p1 = { {0,4,2,2},{6,0,0,4},{0,0,6,4},{8,4,0,0}};
    matrix p2 = { {0,6,4,4},{4,0,3,4},{0,2,8,6},{6,4,5,0}};
    matrix p3 = { {0,6,4,4},{4,3,0,4},{1,0,8,6},{6,4,6,0}};

    cout << "p1 = " << check(p1) << endl;
    cout << "p2 = " << check(p2) << endl;
    cout << "p3 = " << check(p3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как еще вывести позиции тех самых выбранных нулей?

Comment: видите проверки вида "if (m[j][i] == 0) count++;"? вот там и добавляйте вывод.  Думаю, что то вида `if (m[j][i] == 0) cout << i << "," << j << endl;` будет достаточно.

Comment: У вас заданные все матрицы выполняют условие задания, но возвращаемое значение разное. 
Например:
{ {0,0,0},{4,3,0},{0,0,1}};
должно вернуть true, так как "можно" выбрать нулевой элемент в каждом столбце и строке

Comment: Тогда нужно спросить автора, что имелось ввиду под словом по одному.

Comment: Да, нужно было добавить "хотя бы по одному ... "

Comment: Или строго по одному

Comment: p.s. я автор..)

Comment: Тогда в моем решении нужно кол-во сравнивать не на равенство 1, а на больше нуля.

Comment: if (count != 1) на if (count > 0)?

Comment: Ой. Не туда посмотрел. На равенство нулю конечно же.

Comment: Поменял на if (count == 0), но на такую матрицу возвращает 1
matrix p1 = { {0,6,4,4},{4,0,0,4},{0,2,8,6},{6,4,0,0}};

Comment: К сожалению, начальное условие поменялось. Я рассчитывал не под него. Надо думать.